# TypeLoadException before executing the code in Windows Runtime 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, typeloadexception

I am initializing log as below.

```
protected void InitializeLogging (string logFolderStoragePath)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty (logFolderStoragePath)) {
        logFolderStoragePath = _externalStorageFolderPath;
    }

    string settingsIniFilePath = Path.Combine (logFolderStoragePath, _settingsFileName);

     if (_fileSystem.FileExists(settingsIniFilePath))
     {
        FileIniDataParser iniFile = new FileIniDataParser();
        IniData data = iniFile.ReadFile(settingsIniFilePath);
     }
 }
```

I am calling function as:

```
InitializeLogging (logFolderStoragePath);
```

While executing above line, I am getting exception as:

> An exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in
>   App.Forms.WindowsPhoneShared.DLL but was not handled in user code
>        Additional information: Could not load type 'System.ICloneable' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'.

[image]

Even though I have set break-point in `InitializeLogging` function, its not even entering that function, its throwing exception before that. To find exactly where its breaking I commented one by one and found because of below line.

```
IniData data = iniFile.ReadFile(settingsIniFilePath);
```

If you see, I am reading `iniFile` only if `settingsIniFilePath` exist, but the file itself doesn't exist, still it throws exception.